# Which slider is this website using http://siteflu.com/

Tags: javascript, slider

How can I get a slider that looks like [siteflu.com](http://siteflu.com/). I have searched on Internet but found layer slider, revolution slider but no one is like this one.

Comment: This question is rather vague. I went to that link but couldn't see any slider. What page is the slider on? What specifically do you want to replicate about the slider? How do the sliders you've mentioned not meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of the page you will find this
http://siteflu.com/js/masterslider/js/masterslider.min.js

Answer (score 0):

This is the one they are using:
http://www.masterslider.com/